# finding inputs to a calculation to optimize a particular output

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write some haskell code that calculates a property given some inputs to it. I'll be generic since I have a few different applications I'd like to do with this style of program.

```
--some random calculation
longCalc a b c d e f g = a*b+c-d/e*f+g
```

I want to find the combination of inputs that gives the lowest result. So I generate a list of pairs.

```
allPairs = [(show [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], longCalc a b c d e f g) | a<-[1..40],b<-[1..40],c<-[1..40],d<-[1..40],e<-[1..40],f<-[1..40],g<-[1..40]]

minimum' :: Ord a => [(t, a)] -> (t, a)
minimum' []     = error "minimum of empty list"
minimum' (x:xs) = minTail x xs
  where minTail currentMin [] = currentMin
        minTail (m, n) (p:ps)
          | n > (snd p) = minTail p ps
          | otherwise   = minTail (m, n) ps
```

Now I have a list with a descriptor of what the inputs were along with the answer.

bestAnswer = minimum' allPairs

I'm not so sure this is the most efficient way of doing this calculation.

In addition I would like to see a progressive calculation of the best answer.

```
onlyLessFunc f _ [] = []
onlyLessFunc f y (x:xs)
 | f(x) < f(y) = [x] ++ onlyLessFunc f x xs
 | otherwise = onlyLessFunc f x xs
```

This function should produce a list where only better results get added to the end.

How might I go about making this more efficient? I am currently seeing that my approach uses tons of memory (all of it to be specific).

Comment: Well even if you manage to boost the algorithm to calculate the minimum, that will not do much better. The bottleneck here looks like the fact that you use a *generate and test* approach. Constraint programming (and integer linear programming) try to boost efficiency by restricting the domains of the variables.

Comment: Take a look at http://travis.athougies.net/posts/2018-04-23-combinatorial-optimization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boost the efficiency of your proposed `minimum'` with:

```
minimum' :: Ord a => [(t, a)] -> (t, a)
minimum' [] = error "minimum of empty list"
minimum' (x:xs) = minTail x xs
    where minTail m@(xm, fm) (xf@(x, f): xs) | f < fm = minTail xf xs
                                             | otherwise = minTail m xs
          minTail cm [] = cm
```

with some extra techniques, we can definitely boost it a but further, but in general this will not boost performance significantly.

A second optimization that *will* have a huge impact on the use of memory, is *not* to construct such function with `allPairs`, but to pass the list immediately into the function. Now Haskell can garbage collect the list elements that are already evaluated. So we can call it with:

```
minimum' [([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], longCalc a b c d e f g) | a<-[1..40],b<-[1..40],c<-[1..40],d<-[1..40],e<-[1..40],f<-[1..40],g<-[1..40]]
```

But still we will not boost the algorithm to the levels that constraint programming and integer linear programming can. Usually those mechanisms aim to exploit relations in the function, and thus restrict the domains of the variables from the moment a first value is calculated. For *integer linear programming (ILP)* this is usually done with an optimization technique called *cutting plane*.

As for your second question, again we can not boost this in terms of time complexity, but we can boost performance with:

```
onlyLessFunc f y = go (f y)
    where go _ [] = []
          go fy (x:xs) | fx < fy = x : go fx xs
                       | otherwise = go fy xs
              where fx = f x
```

But again, as said, you are actually trying to optimize the wrong part of the algorithm. Usually it is more beneficial to prevent generating all those values in the first place.

Comment: I found the second recommendation interesting. I dug a little deeper into it and found that for GHCI, this definitely is true for total memory usage. I found no difference when compiled with ghc. I suspect this is because of the way ghci keeps named data.

Comment: @uglyoldbob: well if you name it, usually Haskell will keep a reference to the *start* of the list. Since you iterate over it, because the start of the list is alive, all the rest of the elements already calculated remain alive as well, and thus are not garbage collected. If you however do *not* name the list comprehension, then there is no reason to keep the entire list alive at all. So each time a node of the list is processed, we can immediately forget about that. Haskell has some optimizations in place where there are no nodes generated at all. Do you compile with the `-O2` flag?

Comment: Indeed I am using the -02 flag for compiling. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you